# Gulp plumber cannot pipe to undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-less

I am trying, to write a module that when gulp is watching a task, and a Less file changed with some error, it should give a message to the console, but it should not crash the system, which it does no:
This is the code I have written:

```
var onError = function (err) {  
  console.log(err);
};

gulp.task('styles', function () {  
   gulp.src('./{views}/**/*.{less}')
     .pipe(plumber({
       errorHandler: onError
     }))
     .pipe(less())
     .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles/common.css'));
 });
```

When I run the above code, I get the error below:

```
'styles' errored after 20 ms
Error in plugin 'plumber'
Message:
    Can't pipe to undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I have installed gulp-less, and I figured out the solution for this problem aswell:
It should be as follow:

```
  gulp.task('mystyle', function () {  
    gulp.src('build/stylesfiles.less').pipe(plumber()).pipe(less()).
    pipe(gulp.dest ('build/styles/assets'));
    });
```

Basically I do not need the Error message, it will give me a default error, which can get my job done.Using the above code will make sure it runs, and gives me my error, but not crash the server....but thank you "Apercu"

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same error. I resolved it by adding () after the plumber. Here is the code.

Earlier Code:

```
gulp.task('scripts',function(){
gulp.src('admin-scripts.js')
    .pipe(plumber)
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));

});
```

Fixed Code:

```
gulp.task('scripts',function(){
gulp.src('admin-scripts.js')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));

});
```

I was missing the () after plumber. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have installed *gulp-less* using

```
npm install --save-dev
```

and referencing it in your *gulpfile* with

```
var less = require('gulp-less');
```

This error from *plumber* occurs when the destination of your pipe (here your *less*) is undefined.

Also why are you using the `{}` here ? They are a bit useless I think since you're targetting only one thing in it, you could remove them.